# App crashed when I load on the device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I did a pedometer using the accelerometer. At the beginning, It load perfectly in the simulator but in the device crashed. First it was working until the if.

This is the code:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
 import android.hardware.Sensor;
 import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
 import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
 import android.hardware.SensorManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.SystemClock;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Chronometer;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.List;

 public class RunActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, View.OnClickListener {

     TextView x,y,z,e,l;
     double x1,y1,z1, g;
     private int total= 0;
     private Chronometer chronometer;
     Button start, stop;

     private  Sensor mAccelerometer;

     @Override

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_run);
         x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xID);
         y = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yID);
         z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zID);
         e = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);



         this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Rchronometer);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starttime);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endtime);

}

protected void onResume()

{
    super.onResume();
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    if (sensors.size() > 0)
    {
        sm.registerListener(this, sensors.get(0), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
}
protected void onPause()
{
    SensorManager mSensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onStop()
{
    SensorManager mSensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
    super.onStop();
}


@Override

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    this.x.setText("X = "+event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X]);
    this.y.setText("Y = "+event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y]);
    this.z.setText("Z = "+event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z]);


    x1=event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
    y1=event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
    z1=event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

    g = (Math.sqrt((x1*x1)+(y1*y1)+(z1*z1)))/9.8;


    if (g<1){
        total++;
        e.setText(total);
    }
}
@Override

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.starttime:

            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();
            break;
        case R.id.endtime:
            chronometer.stop();
            break;
  `  }
     }
 }
```

Also, this is logcat. I'm not sure what is happening

```
 E/SensorManager: Exception dispatching input event.
 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                   Process: com.paola.trition, PID: 6667
                   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Nothing. It does not appear anything

Comment: You should have your device plugged in when you try to launch the app, in debug mode, and your IDE open so that you can check your logcat when the app crashes. It _should_ be showing you the stack trace so you can track your issue.

Comment: Please post the log or console output